# Is this the right way to solve an integral which has an absolute value?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following integral:

$I(t)=\int_{0}^{s}e^{-|t-y|}dy$

Where $t$ and $s$ are constants. To solve this should I consider the two cases $t>s$ and $t<s$ seperately?

i.e. should I write, when $t>s$:

$I(t)=\int_{0}^{s}e^{y-t}dy$

and when $t<s$:

$I(t)=\int_{0}^{t}e^{y-t}dy+\int_{t}^{s}e^{t-y}dy$

Comment: $I(x)$ is independent of integral you wrote.

Comment: Is the method right though now that that's been fixed?